# How to add data to existing child in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout

In my firebase database,i have users resister data. I want to add  images in the existing data of the users. So the process will be from one activity i want to add other details in the database in user child and  from another activity i want to store image link to the same child(user) because the image will store in firestore. If some one suggest me how to achieve it, i will be very thankful.

Comment: please add your code snippet where you are storing the data and where you want to add the image to your user

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show us what have you tried so far. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way

Here **cities** is main root table and **LA** is Document and **name** **state** **country** is column so when you try to edit or add any new column you have to follow same step but when you are editing only one field then you have to pass only one column all other column value will be same. And if you are adding new one then pass only new key it will add new column and old one same as it is. So on this way you can understand how it's works.

```
    val city = hashMapOf(
        "name" to "Los Angeles",
        "state" to "CA",
        "country" to "USA"
)

db.collection("cities").document("LA")
        .set(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e) }
```